# XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it warning and how to deal with it?

Tags: xml, hosting

I'm trying to host a file in order to make an app for google hangout. I'm hosting it through my webhost, but for some reason the xml is being debugged when i got to access it, and it says that there is a problem. a link to the file that i need: [the file](http://www.wecombineminds.com/googleHangout/simpleHangoutApp.xml). You should see that there is a message on the page about the xml file containing errors. I have no idea why this is happening.. What should i do in order to resolve the issue? thanks

Answer (score 9):

What the "error" means is that there is no stylesheet information provided on how to display the page. Stylesheets are required when viewing an xml in a browser.It's just a warning not an error.There may not be anything wrong structurally with the xml file.

To check if an XML is valid,I use http://validator.w3.org/

Just copy and paste your address to see if the XML is well formed or not.

Comment: I don't think there should be a stylesheet unless the page is meant to be viewed by the user.