# Having troble with vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I would like the path from the hard drive(example-C:\Moje_web_app\examplesite.com\BackUp\logo.logo1.jpg) to show it on the website(vb.net) logo.jpg but I find the next message, what should I do?

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   'C:\Moje_web_app\examplesite.com\BackUp\logo\logo2.jpg'.
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllBytes(String path, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String path)    at
>   AltosWebService.GetLogo() in c:\Users\Korisnik\documents\visual studio
>   2013\WebSites\examplesite.com\App_Code\AltosWebService.vb:line 109

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the filename C:\Moje_web_app\examplesite.com\BackUp\logo\logo2.jpng

It is likely to have the file extension typing error for `jpg`.

Comment: Ok, I'm not the speed saw that I did not put * jpg ... Now, I have the this message?
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<base64Binary xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">...</base64Binary>

Comment: @ZoranJovanovic I think you'd better search with the error message for solution, then you update your question after doing some simple research.   e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035623/xml-file-does-not-appear-to-have-any-style-information-associated-with-it-warnin

Answer (score 0):

The user credentials running your website process (presumably IIS) does not have permissions to read that folder.

What is the physical path to web root?